# How to acces the author name and other docx metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, docx

I want to use C# to get the metadata of a file, for example a docx.
In the screenshot below you see the auteur and other metadata of a file.

[image: Example]

How do I write this metadata to the console?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684368/how-to-read-metadata-information-from-docx-documents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Comment: @PranavPatel It i similar but not the same, the question you show asks how eddit this data non-programmatic, i want to write this data to the console

Comment: @Peterverleg read the answer carefully in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684368/how-to-read-metadata-information-from-docx-documents , it also provided full project demo

Comment: here is the demo solution https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AF_z1mFM432Nt8c&cid=6514BC76687E775B&id=6514BC76687E775B%21131&parId=6514BC76687E775B%21124&action=locate

Comment: If you can use Word automation, just pick them out of [Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196862.aspx)

Comment: Thank you I will check if it is a duplicate and if it is i will close my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word file in DOCX is packaged as a zip file.  The metadata is in an XML file within that zip file.
As a *very simple* way to think about it, this is what you would need to do programmatically through C#:

1. Unzip the DOCX file into it's folder structure.
2. Open the core.xml file located in the docProps folder of that structure.
3. Pull out and store the relevant XML elements that you are looking for, such as
   title, subject or whatever.
4. Write those elements with Console.WriteLine().

[Image Showing Structure and XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5mN.png)

[Info on Office Open XML format](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisrae/2010/09/25/where-is-the-documentation-for-offices-docxxlsxpptx-formats-part-1-office-2007/)