# Fetch Owner or Author property of the docx document c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Currently in order to fetch the Owner or Author of a document we are using the code below:

```
FileSecurity security = FileInfoGetAccessControl();
if (security != null)
{
  System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = (System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)security.GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
  m_sAuthor = sid.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value;
}
```

However, this is giving us Last Modified user instead for Owner for docx files

i.e. if Author = "testuser1" and Last Modified By = "testuser2", then the above code returns "testuser2" instead of "testuser1".

We need the Author property to be fetched. How can we achieve that in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read metadata information from docx documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684368/how-to-read-metadata-information-from-docx-documents)

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. Can you please guide us as to what can be used to achieve the same for doc file also (which are not openxml) files