# How can I replicate programmatically in VBS what Word does when I insert a "built-in" property from the Insert->QuickPart->Document Property dropdown?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

In Microsoft Word (Windows desktop version from around 2007 and later), I can use the Insert Tab, Text group, Explore Quick Parts dropdown, Document Property dropdown to insert a *Content Control* that allows display/entry/selection of the value of one of a number of types of *Document Property*, which might be one of the following:

- Built-in document properties
- "Content Type" metaproperties associated with a server such as Microsoft's SharePoint server

How can I do programmatic insertion of "built-in" document properties using VBScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example assumes that you want to insert a content control mapped to one of Word's built-in properties at a current valid selection in Windows Desktop Word (i.e. in an open document). Please see the following notes.

```
Option Explicit

' a simple test - assume a document is open in Word
' and you want to insert a "Property Content Control"
' at the current selection

Dim wapp
Set wapp = Getobject(,"Word.Application")
Call insertAndMapProperty(wapp.Selection.Range,"companyfax")
Set wapp = Nothing

Sub insertAndMapProperty(Location, PropertyName) ' As Word.Range, As String
' Location is a Word Range where you want to insert the Content Control
' 
' pass the name of the element (since it does not change when you change the user interface language)

Select Case LCase(Trim(PropertyName))
Case "abstract"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "Abstract", "Abstract"
Case "category"
  setMSCoreProps Location, "category", "Category"
Case "company"
  setExtendedProps Location, "Company", "Company"
Case "contentstatus"
  setMSCoreProps Location, "contentStatus", "Status"
Case "creator"
  setDCoreProps Location, "creator", "Author"
Case "companyaddress"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "CompanyAddress", "Company Address"
Case "companyemail"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "CompanyEmail", "Company E-mail"
Case "companyfax"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "CompanyFax", "Company Fax"
Case "companyphone"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "CompanyPhone", "Company Phone"
Case "description"
  setDCoreProps Location, "description", "Comments"
Case "keywords"
  setMSCoreProps Location, "keywords", "Keywords"
Case "manager"
  setExtendedProps Location, "Manager", "Manager"
Case "publishdate"
  setCoverPageProps Location, "PublishDate", "Publish Date"
Case "subject"
  setDCoreProps Location, "subject", "Subject"
Case "title"
  setDCoreProps Location, "title", "Title"
Case Else
    Wscript.Echo "Unrecognized property name: " & PropertyName 
End Select

End Sub

Sub setCoverPageProps(Location, PropertyName, TitlePlaceHolder)
Const missing = Nothing
Const coverPageMappings = "xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps'"
With Location.ContentControls.Add(1) '1=wdContentControlText
  .Title = TitlePlaceHolder
  .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:" & PropertyName & "[1]", coverPageMappings, missing
  .SetPlaceHolderText missing, missing, "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]"
End With
End Sub

Sub setDCoreProps(Location, PropertyName, TitlePlaceHolder)
Const missing = Nothing
Const DCoreMappings = "xmlns:ns0='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:ns1='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties'"
With Location.ContentControls.Add(1)
  .Title = TitlePlaceHolder
  .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/ns1:coreProperties[1]/ns0:" & PropertyName & "[1]", DCoreMappings, missing
  .SetPlaceHolderText missing, missing, "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]"
End With
End Sub

Sub setMSCoreProps(Location, PropertyName, TitlePlaceHolder)
Const missing = Nothing
Const MSCoreMappings = "xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties'"
With Location.ContentControls.Add(1)
  .Title = TitlePlaceHolder
  .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/ns0:coreProperties[1]/ns0:" & PropertyName & "[1]", MSCoreMappings, missing
  .SetPlaceHolderText missing, missing, "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]"
End With
End Sub

Sub setExtendedProps(Location, PropertyName, TitlePlaceHolder)
Const missing = Nothing
Const extendedMappings = "xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties'"
With Location.ContentControls.Add(1)
  .Title = TitlePlaceHolder
  .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/ns0:Properties[1]/ns0:" & PropertyName & "[1]", extendedMappings, missing
  .SetPlaceHolderText missing, missing, "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]"
End With
End Sub
```

Notes:-

By "valid selection", I mean a selection that won't cause a Word error/exception. I.e., you will need to do a lot more to avoid exceptions.

The descriptive (Title, Placeholder) texts here are for when you insert these controls with the Word User Interface Language set to English (and possibly only some specific English versions). If your interface language is, say, French, you might prefer to use the French equivalents for the Content Control Title and Placeholder. It is not obvious how you might discover those texts from the Word Object Model.

There are a number of different types of "property" in Word, including

- builtin core properties
- builtin app properties
- builtin extended properties
- builtin CoverPageProps properties
- legacy user-defined properties (Word Custom Document Properties)
- content-type properties
- (arguably) Word Document Variables
- programmer defined elements/attributes in Word Custom XML Parts.

You can insert the values of a lot of these properties using traditional Word "Field Codes" To insert values without using VBA (say), you need a Content Control mapped to a CustomXMLPart.

Within a .docx type document file (.docx, .docm, .dotx, .dotm),  builtin core properties, builtin app properties, and builtin extended properties are stored in predefined .xml files. e.g. app.xml etc. However, when Word opens such a document, it builds two Word CustomXMLParts. Another standard custom XML part holds the values of the "CoverPageProps"

You can map a Content Control to any element or attribute within a Custom XML Part, including these parts. But Word does not replicate the values of builtin document properties such as "Number of Words", in CustomXML Parts, and that means that there is no builtin way to insert a *Content Control* that displays the number of Words in a document, or a *Content Control* that displays the value of a User-Defined Document Property.

Comment: Tested the code. I had to make a few minor changes to get it working as a VBscript inside a word document.

Mainly: (1) remove ```Const missing = Nothing```, which doesn't work and replace everywhere missing by Nothing | 
(2) replace Wscript.Echo by MsgBox | 
(3) remove the VBS code and create an entry function for word (ie. remove ```Dim Wap.[...]Set wapp=Nothing```

Comment: GMCB Thanks for the feedback. "Inside" a Word document makes it sound as if you are using VBA, not VBScript as specified in your original question. If so, yes, you would do things a little differently - if you've already got a reference to the Word Application you don't need that part, and you shouldn't need the "Nothing" parameters at all - just e.g. .SetPlaceHolderText , , "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]" or use a named parameter .SetPlaceHolderText Text:= "[" & TitlePlaceHolder & "]"

Comment: You are right. I accidentally mentioned VBS instead of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Very great answer. For those interested to included other mapped properties, including those from SharePoint for instance, here is a StackOverflow post which gives further details on how to find the path to the XML properties: [MS Word adding via VBA Custom Document Properties from SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311197/ms-word-adding-via-vba-custom-document-properties-from-sharepoint/).

In brief:

1. Create an MS Word file in SharePoint library (with some user columns), and/or load custom XML properties in your file (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-document-level-customizations?view=vs-2019))
2. Insert in the word file the control content manually to the properties you are interested in
3. Change word file extension to .zip
4. Extract [documentName.docx.zip]\word\document.xml document contained in the archive
5. Open the file with my favorite XML editor
6. You can then find the general path of the document at the following element\attributes: <w:dataBinding w:prefixMappings="[rootOfProperties]" w:xpath="[pathToProperties]" ....>
7. This information plugs into the code provided above.

NOTE: it might be possible to access the full details of the XML content as described in step 1-6, via the "Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool", as explained in this StackOverflow post: [How to read metadata information from docx documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684368/how-to-read-metadata-information-from-docx-documents/9700955#9700955)